# Laravel : How can I reduce duplicate codes?

Tags: php, laravel

I don't want to add $c1, $c2, $c3, ... infinitely.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
public function comment() {
    $c1 = Comment::where('parent_id', $this->id)->pluck('id');
    $c2 = Comment::whereIn('parent_id', $c1)->pluck('id');
    $c3 = Comment::whereIn('parent_id', $c2)->pluck('id');
    $c4 = Comment::whereIn('parent_id', $c3)->pluck('id');
  
    $comments = Comment::query()
    ->where('parent_id', $this->id)
    ->orWhereIn('parent_id', $c1)
    ->orWhereIn('parent_id', $c2)
    ->orWhereIn('parent_id', $c3)
    ->orWhereIn('parent_id', $c4);
    
    return $comments ;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? So that we do not misunderstand you. - And what version of php / laravel are you running?

Comment: You can pass variables $c1,$c2.... as array. it will reduce the code

Comment: Most likely comments can have comments and these comments can again have comments an unlimited amount of times. So the author wants to look up all comments in a "deep" way.

Comment: There are probably easier ways to get (recursive) comments

Comment: $items = Item::whereIn('id', [1,2,..])->get(); like this

Comment: Refer [Multi-tiered Comment Replies: Display and Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4060252/8053274)

Comment: It looks like you're looking for a nested set: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: @Stoff php 7.3 and laravel 5.3

Comment: Comment B reply to Comment A.
Comment C reply to Comment B.
Comment D reply to Comment C.
When deleting comment A, I want comments B, C, D to be deleted.

Comment: It might be worth having a look at [Nested Sets](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset) for something like this. Failing that, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query) may help if you're using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
$c1 = Comment::where('parent_id', $this->id)->pluck('id');
for($i = 1;$i<=4;$i++) {
    @${'c'.$i} = Comment::whereIn('parent_id', @${'c'.$i})->pluck('id');
}
```

Well, the part in the query I'm not sure how to make it automatically added it. But if using DB::raw('') maybe but I'm not how much $c1,$c2,$c3,$c4,$c5 you want.

Comment: It shows error Undefined variable: c

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: It shows error Undefined variable: c0

Comment: Where exactly does it give you undefined variable c0? The code states that $i is never 0. As such, this code does not contain C0.

Comment: Yes i change it about to add a comment but didn't click the added button

Answer (score 1):

**Make self relations in Comment model**

**Comment.php**

```
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function child()
{
    return $this->hasOne(self::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

**going top to bottom in heirarchy**

**CommentController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
......
$parent = $this;
$ids= new Collection();

while ($parent->child) { // loop will stop if parent has no child
    $ids->push($parent->child->id);
    $parent = $parent->child; // make child as parent to continue loop to get child of child
}

$comments = Comment::whereIn('parent_id', $ids)->get()
```

**going bottom to top in heirarchy**

**CommentController.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
......
$child= $this;
$ids= new Collection();

while ($child->parent) { // loop will stop if parent has no child
    $ids->push($child->parent->id);
    $child= $child->parent; // make child as parent to continue loop to get child of child
}

$comments = Comment::whereIn('parent_id', $ids)->get()
```

**If you have comment with many replies and replies of replies and you want to get top parent comment and all of his replies so you can do it like this**

**Comment.php**

```
// This relation will work like loop it will get all replies with replies
//because it call ->with() function on each instance
public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id')->with('replies);
}
```

**CommentController.php**

```
use App\Models\Comment;
.......
return Comment::where('parent_id', null) // This condition get top parent comment 
               ->with('replies')
               ->get()
```

**And you can call relation on instance to get his replies**

```
return $parentComment->replies;
```

Comment: Please help me fix this https://i.ibb.co/8gKsf80/Screenshot-14277.jpg
Now it only shows comments in the green frame. How to make it show comments in the orange frame too? Because it is a child of comment 1.

Comment: First of all, I add another section to my answer at the last, take a look, may it increase your knowledge, And let me know how many levels of replies do you want? If it is limited so you can add a column named level in the comments table and can easily track the level of reply. If it has an infinity of levels so we will find a solution for that.
Happy coding :-)

Comment: Yes, it has infinite levels of replies.

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/what-is-a-good-way-to-display-infinite-nested-comments
Please also check Facebook comment modal .